# Jquery if NOT div or any of its contents, do this

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a sidepanel that slides out from the right at the click of a button, and then slides back in if you click outside of the panel.

In the following code it slides in when any element inside the div#sidepanel is clicked, because their 'id' is not 'sidepanel. How do I include any and all elements inside the div#sidepanel? I atempted...

```
if (e.target != $('div#sidepanel).find(*)){};
```

The code is as follows:

```
$("main").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'opensidepanel') {
    $("div#sidepanel").animate({
      right: '0px'
    });
  } else if (e.target.id != 'sidepanel') {
    $("div#sidepanel").animate({
      right: '-340px'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code(css html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `has`:

```
else if (!$("#sidepanel").has(e.target)) {
```

Depending on whether a click on the side panel itself (not a child element of it) should also be excluded, you may need to extend:

```
else if (!$("#sidepanel").has(e.target) && e.target.id != 'sidepanel') {
```

Obviously, much depends on what `#main` is in your page, as you are only capturing clicks in that area. You might want to just listen to click events on the whole document.

Comment: This works, but I ended up using `else if (!$(e.target).closest('#sidepanel').length){}`